# Supremum property on ordered fields.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose $X$ is non-empty subset of non-negative $(x\geq0)$  elements in a field $\mathbb{F}$ which is bounded above.
The sequence $(c_k)$ is defined as follows, Let $k$ be a natural number.
$$b_k=\inf\{m \in \mathbb{N}: m \geq 2^k x, \forall x\in X\}, \,\,\, c_k=\frac{b_k}{2^k}$$
How to prove $\sup X = c$? I can prove $ \sup X \leq c$, $c$ is limit of the sequence.

My question is how to extend this idea for set that contains negative elements. If atleast one non-negative element is there, we can do the same thing (Is it?) . But how to do if all elements are negative? This method can not be used here I guess we get $\sup X=0$ if we use this method. Can we extend this idea to that or we should prove seperately?

Every bounded increasing sequence converges. That is the assumptions on the field.

Comment: First you need to state that $\Bbb{F}$ is an **ordered** field. But you need than that to make your question make sense. The $\sup$ operation is not defined for all non-empty bounded sets in an arbitrary ordered field. Are you working in $\Bbb{R}$, or some general **complete** ordered field, or what? Oh, I see you did put the word ordered in your title: you should make the body of your MSE questions self-contained.

Comment: If $\Bbb F\subset \Bbb R$ and if $X\ne\{0\}.$ Prove $b_{k+1}\le 2b_k,$ so  $c_k\ge c_{k+1}\ge c.$ Suppose $ 0<d=c-\sup X.$  Take $k\in\Bbb N$ large enough that $1/2^k<d$ and $b_k>1.$ Then  $b_k-1\in\Bbb N$ but $(b_k-1)/2^k=c_k-1/2^k\ge c-1/2^k>\sup X,$ contrary to the definition of $b_k.$